# only alpha and only numeric regex issue

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex in Java:

```
private static final String ALPHA_REGEX = "[^A-Za-z]+$";
```

If I input say "a334234234" the validation will fail. However if I input "a3423423fsfsdf" the validation succeeds...

Same goes for the following regex which checks whether the input is numeric only:

```
private final static    Pattern NUMBER_ONLY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[^0-9 ]+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

If I input 4saasd the validation fails, but if I input 3dfsdf22 the validation is successful. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` in `[]` mean `not`, but without `[]` it means beginning of string, this is your issue

`^[a-zA-Z]+$` - only letter

`^\d+$` - only digit